# how to check that the value is already in the table using EXISTS?

Tags: python, postgresql, discord.py

I'm writting a discord bot and I need to cheak that the value is already in the table. I was looking for how to do this and realized that I need to use EXISTS. But I didn’t understand how to implement it into my code:

```
@tasks.loop(count=1)
async def on_ready():
    """The on_ready function is executed when the bot starts up and creates theusers table in the database, also adds names, id, number of xp and the server of all to the database participants who are not in the database.
    """
    await bot.wait_until_ready()
    DiscordComponents(bot)
    cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
                    name VARCHAR(255), 
                    id BIGSERIAL NOT NULL, 
                    xp INT,
                    id_row SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
                );""")
    for guild in bot.guilds:
        for member in guild.members:
            if member.id not in bots:
                cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO users VALUES ('{}', {}, {});""".format(member, member.id, 0))
    connect.commit()
    print("Bot connected!")
```

Can you help me?

Comment: `Duplicate` of your own [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70054505/how-to-write-a-check-for-uniqueness-of-a-value-in-a-postgresql-database) ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write a check for uniqueness of a value in a PostgreSQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70054505/how-to-write-a-check-for-uniqueness-of-a-value-in-a-postgresql-database)

Comment: you can add in your `INSERT` statement the clause `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING` see the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html)